# req.session created by cookie-session middleware of express is not accessable in other subroute

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, cookie-session

session package of npm for implementing authorization and authentication in app.js(nodejs) statement is written like

```
app.use(cookieSession({
  name: 'wrtpsess',
  keys: ["dsfewfsffe3243efds"],
  // Cookie Options
  maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 24 hours
  path: "/panel/writerpanel",
  sameSite:"lax"
}))
```

in frontend(reactjs) i am setting userid to session on path `/panel/writerpanel/loginpage` i checked session was available on this path but when i am trying to access session on route `/panel/writerpanel/homepage(onreactjs)` req.session returns undefined why?? as you can in nodejs file(app.js as given above) path is /panel/writerpanel so both `/panel/writerpanel/loginpage` and `/panel/writerpanel/homepage` are the subroute of panel/writerpanel only they must have access to req.session.
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i forget to write proper package name its cookie-session package from npm for express

Comment: @BabakAbadkheir i couldn't get you